# Installed program not visible to all users

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.6

I am using wix setup to install some package. When I install it, it appears in "Programs and Features" in control panel. It is visible to some users not all, and they can uninstall it as well. 
Problem is when the other user who can not see what I installed in control panel, when he installs something I can't see it. I can install the same package again and it won't complain that it already exists.

Comment: This question could be improved by posting what you've already tried doing to resolve the problem, or by noting what research you've done already that's failed to solve the problem.

Comment: Your suggestion could be improved by not marking someone's question as unresearched effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InstallScope="perMachine"` need to be set for the package node under product node.

```
<Product Id="51552DB5-AE93-44D0-87B1-0EB93B64182D" >
 <Package InstallerVersion="200"
          Compressed="yes"
          InstallScope="perMachine"
          InstallPrivileges="elevated" />
</Product>
```

Answer (score 4):

MSI packages are installed [per-user or per-machine](http://setupanddeployment.com/installation-environment/peruser-permachine/). Only **per-machine** products are accessible by all users.

Try making your installation per-machine by setting [ALLUSERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property to:

```
1
```