# Register Class Per Machine

Tags: c#, wix, installation, registry, wix3.5

I create a WIX installer for a dll.

There is a class element that register the class of the dll in the registry.

```
<Class Id="{1AF5E2B9-CC02-368F-A879-1DF3F538D71A}"   
       Context="InprocServer32"
       Description="AdminAddins.MyClass"  
       ThreadingModel="both"
       ForeignServer="mscoree.dll">
   <ProgId Id="AdminAddins.MyClass" Description="AdminAddins.MyClass" />
</Class>  

<RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{1AF5E2B9-CC02-368F-A879-1DF3F538D71A}  
\Implemented Categories\{62C8FE65-4EBB-45e7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}"   
Value="" Type="string" Action="write" />
```

However, it always registered under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.

Is there a way to explicitly refer the class to be registered under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`?

Comment: Is your general installation per-user and you want to install only this per-machine, or do you want to install everything per-machine? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081670/installed-program-not-visible-to-all-users

Comment: @Herman, Thanks. What is the difference? If I do not set the property of `allusers` to a hard-coded value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not set the ALLUSERS property it defaults to per user, so the installed product will work only for the installing user. If it's a single-user machine then that's fine and if the app works then maybe you don't need to worry. A per user install creates COM registration just for that user, not everyone who might log on.

If you want the app to be available for all potential users who log on the system then force ALLUSERS to be 1 and the per machine registration will go in HKLM, assuming that the installing user has the privilege to create entries there.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367559(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. What about an installer which enables the user to select if to install per user or per machine? Then, I cannot hard-coded the `ALLUSERS` property. Any ideas?

Comment: I think in the WiX world that's in the advanced dialog  http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/dialog_reference/wixui_advanced.html

Comment: Yes, In advanced installer I don't have to hard-coded the `ALLUSERS` property, but what about the class COM registry (`<RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{69A5C0F7-D8A2-392A-9DDA-6CB9DC1E4027} Value="" Type="string" Action="write" />`) should it be hard-coded to `HKLM` or `HKCU`?

Comment: Advanced Installer? I don't know what you mean - I referred to the WiX dialog set called "advanced", look at the link I supplied. I'm confused because you are now referring to registry entries. The Class table just does the right thing depending on ALLUSERS. You did per user so it went to HKCU. If you do per machine it goes to HKLM.

Comment: Yes, The class is sent to the registry entry according to the `ALLUSERS`property, but another part of the class COM registry is the registry entries elements - that you can see after the `class` element in the code I've posted. There, I hard-coded the registry entry to `HKLM`. My question: Does it have to be hard-coded or, like the class, is sent to the right registry entry according to another property value? Thanks.

Comment: If you want a registry entry to go to HKLM or HKCU depending on ALLUSERS, use the WiX HKMU registry root type